# Вывод текста при изменении состояния Radiobutton Python

Tags: python, tkinter, radiobutton

Делаю проект мини-тест, нужно чтобы когда состояние radiobutton'а var1 - менялось на ACTIVE, то в консоль выводился текст, не понимаю как это сделать?

```
var1 = Radiobutton(win, text='У меня отличное настроение', variable = varik, value = 1)
var2 = Radiobutton(win, text='Я чувствую небольшую грусть', variable = varik, value = 2)
var3 = Radiobutton(win, text='Мне грустно и тоскливо', variable = varik, value = 3)
var4 = Radiobutton(win, text='Я постоянно грущу, иногда без повода', variable = varik, 
value = 4)
if var1['state'] == ACTIVE:
print('var1 active')
var1.pack()
var2.pack()
var3.pack()
var4.pack()
```

Comment: Нужно создать функцию-обработчик и добавить ее к кнопкам через атрибут command, смотрите тут: https://metanit.com/python/tutorial/9.8.php

Comment: что-то типа?
`def change():
    if var1['state'] == ACTIVE:
        print('var1 active')
var1 = Radiobutton(win, text='У меня отличное настроение', variable = varik, value = 1, command = change)`

Comment: Да, похоже, на правду :)

Comment: только это все равно не работает :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При клике на радио-кнопки вызывается `change`:

```
from tkinter import *


win = Tk()

r_var = IntVar()
r_var.set(1)


def change():
    value = r_var.get()
    print(f'var{value} active')


r1 = Radiobutton(win, text='У меня отличное настроение', variable=r_var, command=change, value=1)
r2 = Radiobutton(win, text='Я чувствую небольшую грусть', variable=r_var, command=change, value=2)
r3 = Radiobutton(win, text='Мне грустно и тоскливо', variable=r_var, command=change, value=3)
r4 = Radiobutton(win, text='Я постоянно грущу, иногда без повода', variable=r_var, command=change, value=4)

r1.pack()
r2.pack()
r3.pack()
r4.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Можно привязать функцию через `bind`, тогда в функцию будет передаваться событие, а него можно получить виджет

Пример:

```
from tkinter import *


win = Tk()

r_var = IntVar()
r_var.set(1)


def change(event):
    value = r_var.get()
    text = event.widget['text']
    print(f'var{value} active, widget={text!r}')


r1 = Radiobutton(win, text='У меня отличное настроение', variable=r_var, value=1)
r1.bind("<Button-1>", change)
r1.pack()

r2 = Radiobutton(win, text='Я чувствую небольшую грусть', variable=r_var, value=2)
r2.bind("<Button-1>", change)
r2.pack()

r3 = Radiobutton(win, text='Мне грустно и тоскливо', variable=r_var, value=3)
r3.bind("<Button-1>", change)
r3.pack()

r4 = Radiobutton(win, text='Я постоянно грущу, иногда без повода', variable=r_var, value=4)
r4.bind("<Button-1>", change)
r4.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает, а как сделать чтобы всё по тому же нажатию на кнопку, например, менялся текст(на заданный)?

Comment: @4xun, обновил ответ